# anyMatch on list of Mono<Boolean>

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I am getting `Mono<User>` from response, User has a list of subscription, I have to check(through another api) if at least one of them matches the condition and then based on that I have to send further event.

```
Mono<User> user = userFacade.getUser();
user.flatMap(this::hasSub)
    .flatMap(this::sendEvent(Pair.getLeft, Pair.getRight))



Mono<Pair<User,Boolean>> hasSub(User user) {

   Stream<Mono<Boolean>> listOfBooleans= user.getSubscriptions.stream
                           .map(sub -> SubFacade.isPrioSub(sub.getId))//SubFacade returns Mono<Boolean>

   //At this point I am stuck, I need to check if at least one of Stream<Mono<Boolean>> is true, but anyMatch() is arguing about passing Mono<Boolean> into it
   //also to optimize requests it would be nice to have analogue of break to exit iteration once we get Mono<true>, but dropWith() also is not accepting Mono<Boolean>
   return Mono.just(Pair.of(user, 'get boolean from listOfBooleans'))
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
Mono<Pair<User, Boolean>> hasSub(User user) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(user.getSubscriptions())
               .filterWhen(sub -> SubFacade.isPrioSub(sub.getId()))
               .next() // takes the first element passing the filter
               .map(x -> Pair.of(user, true))
               .defaultIfEmpty(Pair.of(user, false));
}
```

Note: this will **sequentially** check the subscriptions for the given user and stop at the first satisfying item. If concurrency is needed then `filterWhen` should be replaced with `flatMap` and `filter`.